# Bind Data to an instance of a class out of datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext, revit

ANSWER BELOW.

So I'm using c# and WPF to create an external command(add-in) for Autodesk Revit.
I've got something like this:

My **View** contains:

```
PWM = new PrintWindowModel(); // this is my ViewModel           
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = PWM;
```

My **ViewModel** contains properties to get and set data. So this part of my databinding works fine.  It also contains this (the entrypoint for Revit):

```
public Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementSet elements)
{
PrintMgr PrintManager = new PrintMgr(commandData);       
  //...
         return Result.Succeeded;
        }
```

PrintMgr is a class that I got from the Revit SDK. It's a very useful class, but needs commandData passed to work. It uses commandData  to set the currentdocument and things a like. Because it needs commandData I see no other option than to instanciate it here.

Now, in my Xaml I have a combobox:

```
<ComboBox Name="AllPrinters"                     
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding GetInstalledPrinters}"                      
                  SelectedItem="{Binding PrintManager.PrinterName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Now, the `ItemsSource` works just fine. No problem here.

The issue lies in with `SelectedItem.` The way I'm binding it is obviously not working. 
(FYI: PrintManager.PrinterName does have a get&set property. )

Now, if my class didn't need commandData, I could just go

```
private PrintMgr _printManager;
Public PrintMgr PrintManager 
{ 
get{return_printManager;}
set { _printManager=value;}
}
```

But since my class DOES need commandData, this won't help.

EDIT:

I added:

```
public string PrinterName 
{
get { return PrintManager.PrinterName; } 
set { PrintManager.PrinterName = value; } 
}
```

and in my Xaml:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding PrinterName}
```

Then I deleted `datacontext=this;` and added `PrintWndow.Datacontext=this;` to the command method.

Comment: Put the `PrinterName` property in the ViewModel. The ViewModel is literally the *model* used by the *view*, not a business entity, a model or service class. In this case a `PrintManager` sounds like a service more than anything. You could delegate the VM's PrinterName property to the PrintManager.PrinterName property, ie have its get/set call the PrintManager

Comment: You can only bind to public properties so you will need to expose the name of the printer from such a one.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I know that's the usual way of binding. 
But how do I do that in this case? 

I can't go:
"Return PrintManager.PrinterName; " outside of that method... because PrintManager is unknown there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to add the PrintManager property in your ViewModel but I suggest that you add a private setter.

```
private PrintMgr _printManager;
public PrintMgr PrintManager 
{ 
    get{return_printManager;}
    private set { _printManager=value;}
}
```

In your ViewModel command handler:

```
public Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementSet elements)
{
     PrintManager = new PrintMgr(commandData);

     //...
     return Result.Succeeded;
}
```

This will update your property every time the command gets executed.

But I think its not your final answer because you still have to think about what if the command get executed multiple times: Do you want to regenerate the PrintManager every time?

And if the command is not executed before the View is rendered, the binding will not work because the PrintManager property will be null.

In that case I have an other solution for you :)

Comment: (Sorry for the mark-up here, Enter posts the comment instead of inserting a new line).  Thanks a lot for the Help!
 This, among the other tips you gave me made it work. Apart from what is said above^ I also added: . public string PrinterName { get { return PrintManager.PrinterName; } set { PrintManager.PrinterName = value; } } . and in my Xaml: . selectedItem="{Binding PrinterName} . Then I deleted datacontext=this; and added PrintWndow.Datacontext=this; to the command method.